# How do I use Microsoft Sync Framework to sync between SQL Server 2008 and a .NET Webservice?

Tags: .net, web-services, blackberry, microsoft-sync-framework

Does anyone have an example of how to use MS Sync framework with .NET webservices?  I have SQL Server 2008, which is exposing data to BlackBerry devices through webservices using regular web methods. Can I use the Sync Framework to expose data through Web Services and to save it back to the database?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand your question, you wish to syncronize two relational databases via a web service. The Sync Framework supports this scenario, as described in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902831.aspx).

I wrote a couple of posts based on my own limited experience with this scenario:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/ploeh/archive/2008/08/26/n-tier-synchronization-with-the-sync-framework-and-wcf-channelfactory-part-1.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/ploeh/archive/2008/08/27/n-tier-synchronization-with-the-sync-framework-and-wcf-channelfactory-part-2.aspx

Comment: No, a BlackBerry with Persistent Object storage is on on end and it communicates with a SQL Server 2008 DB through a webservice.

Comment: You can still use the Sync Framework even for non-relational data destinations, but not the ADO.NET Sync Services (they are different aspects of the same overall package). However, that is a lot more work. In any case you must be able to execute the Sync code on the device, so you must be able to run either .NET (CF) or COM code there.

Comment: If you can run COM code, you can use that instead. Otherwise, you can't use the Sync Framework, unless you can reverse the direction and make the device a server and the service the client. The sync framework doesn't push, it pulls, so you need a host for the pulling code.

Comment: I've installed MS Sync Framework to my SQL 2008 Server, but how do I go about setting up the syncing between my two databases? All Microsoft has to offer are high-level explanations of how it works, but not how to use it